# Find the equation of plane

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Find the equation of the plane in $\mathbb R^3$  which passes through the point $(−10, 5, 4)$ and which is perpendicular to the line joining the points $(4, −1, 2)$ and $(−3, 2, 3)$.

I was trying this question  many times. But I could not get the solution.
I was trying to make two plane equations $4x-y+ 2z =0$ and $-3x + 2y+ 3z =0$
but I don't  know  what is other step to find the equation.

If anbody help me I would be very thankful to him.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If it is perpendicular to the line joining the points that you mentioned, then it is perpendicular to the vector $(7,-3,-1)$. So, its equation is $7x-3y-z=k$, for some $k$. Since you want it to pass through $(-10,5,4)$, what must be the value of $k$?

Comment: how  ( 7,-3,-1) has come  ...i don't understand @ jose carlos santos

Comment: @lomberlego $(7,-3,-1)=(4,-1,2)-(-3,2,3)$.

Comment: thanks but   how can u write like  this,,,,,,  question is about perpendicular@ jose carlos santos

Comment: @lomberlego I don't undestand your doubt.

Comment: i got it ......... actually i didn't read ur solution  carefully, thanks @ jose carlos  santos

Comment: but how  we can find  the value of k @ jose carlos santos

Comment: @lomberlego $k=7\times(-10)-3\times5-4$.

Comment: ok  89 ,, thanks  i got it @ jose carlos santos